# pop3 mail client

Tags: c#, email, client, pop3

I am trying to make my own pop mail client, not using library from the net. So i did this.

[image: code part 1]
[image: code part 2]

As you can see where the red arrows are, that are remains of strings and don't know how to get rid of them.

And at my loop made for the builder append i can not put `for (int = 0; i <= charNumber; i++)` becouse i get and out of index error. So at the end i have to put two `reader.ReadLine();` one for the "." and one so that i can rid of those reamains so that my app doesn't fail.

Any idees ?

Comment: is that a listbox on the leftside of ur screenshot

Comment: yes it just to see the server response